# Exporting data to CSV from multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I am able to export all fields of a model to a CSV file, but now I need to add some attributes from another model which has a has_many relationship with the original.

my controller file looks like

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html 
  format.csv { send_data @students.as_csv, filename: "students-#{Date.today}.csv" }  
end
```

student.rb

```
def self.as_csv
  attributes = %w{surname given_name admission_year admission_no hobbies }
  CSV.generate do |csv|
    csv << attributes
    all.each do |item|
      csv << item.attributes.values_at(*attributes)
    end
  end
```

It works fine but because hobby is another table having a has_many relation with student as a student has many hobbies, I want to show hobbies for each student as a comma separated list in the csv. I am stuck as to how to achieve this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using? Did you try using join(:hobbies) with `all` in `as_csv` method to see if it works?

Comment: I tried but that does not seem to work.

Comment: Am I missing something, is `as_csv` `class` method or `instance` method?

Comment: How did you define the association between `Student` and `Hobby`? What attributes does `Hobby` have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just do something like this:

```
CSV_HEADER = %w[surname given_name admission_year admission_no hobbies]
def self.as_csv
  CSV.generate do |csv|
    csv << CSV_HEADER
    all.each do |student|
      csv << [
        student.surname, 
        student.given_name, 
        student.admission_year,
        student.admission_no,
        student.hobbies.pluck(:title).join(', ')
      ]
    end
  end
end
```

You may need to adjust `title` with a attributes name that returns the hobby as a string.

Comment: This works. Now instead of saving all the records, I need to iterate over a subset of records. This filtering is already been done in the controller and when I say "@students.as_csv", I am passing an argument as "@students" like send_data "@students.as_csv(students)" and in student.rb I am accepting an argument like def self.as_csv(list) and then trying to iterate over this list, but this list is empty.